# Rock-id and mineral-id questions. Status

Tags: discussion

**Status:**

- Every question taged with identification request is a closed
  question.
- Questions related with field or theorical geology were untaged.
- Clouds and instrumentation questions were untaged.
- Fossils questions were untaged (they are easy to find at tag fossils).

---

**Next step: deletion**

- Movies&TV deleted every question.
- Anime and Manga didn't delete some upvoted questions ([link](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3839/identification-request-cleanup-phase-3-final-delete-lock)). But they gave and [historical lock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for) to the questions they saved.

I cannot help on the deletion task because 2k reputation is needed ([recent meta post](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1790/are-we-deleting-closed-questions)).

If the tag is gonna continue existing I offer myself to rescue again clouds id questions (to tag again those questions with id-request) once we delete most, or everyone of the id my rock/mineral ones. @uhoh could also retag his questions about instrumentation if he wish it once the deletion task is done.

Comment: I suspect there is loose of reputation, as at anime manga they didn't delete question with +4 score. ["Please delete all "identification-requests" without a question score of 4 or higher AND at least an answer with a score of 3 or higher."](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3839/identification-request-cleanup-phase-3-final-delete-lock)

Comment: My goodness you've been very busy! Thank you for all of the time and effort. Does "Google won't raster any question." mean that if they are deleted they will eventually stop showing up in searches for "rock identification" and so fewer people will come to the site for rock identification (which would be a good thing)?

Comment: @uho yes. I know it because a recent forum of asperger I found typing "asperger forum", being the first entrance. The site closed. Two weeks later, Google eliminated the entry; it disappeared from searches. If we eliminate the content that has text as "identify", "rock",...., Google won't show us for that queries.

Comment: AIUI you're right that if we delete questions, anybody who has rep from those questions will lose that rep (or gain it, if there were downvotes involved).

Comment: To lock the ancient upvoted questions is another posibility https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126631/486893

Comment: @SemidiurnalSimon as someone who has quite a lot of rep from rock-id questions, I am willing to lose them (twice over tbh) just to get rid of this menace

Comment: Just passed the 2000 rep line but with only 5 delete votes a day it will take some time ;-) BTW Still found some rock ID questions today, but that's not really a surprise; you have to play with search terms like *-[identification-request] is:q what rock closed:no*

Comment: @Jan Doggen Most of them are closed. Here my work ends. gerrit told he could help on october. Myself I have exams for a public job and gonna be out until 2020. Congrats for 2k rep!

Comment: There should be some questions open taged geology. My filter was only id-request and rocks tags.

Comment: Just noticed this effort to clean up id questions because I filtered those out in the first place! I will try to visit often to cast my delete votes over the already closed.