# Are we deleting closed questions?

Tags: discussion, support

A very important part of this entire make-rock-id-q-offtopic story was to delete the old questions so it stops bringing this kind of traffic into the website.

My understanding is that questions have to be closed for a while, and only then they can be deleted.

I cast a delete vote on some of the older closed questions, but we need more than my vote. Apparently there isn't a delete queue like there is for all of the other moderation actions. Some of the question I voted on for deletion still have my vote alone for a very long time now.

Are there any other methods to expedite the deletion of the old closed questions?

Comment: Not that I know of. There are currently only 46 users with the > 2000 rep that is required to (vote to) delete questions. With 5 delete votes per day, and 3 votes required it is going to take some time. I have a browser bookmark https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bidentification-request%5D+closed%3Ayes which I use once a day to cast my 5 votes. Maybe mods can delete quicker?