# 2k+ users Please help delete closed rock ID questions

Tags: support, deleted-questions

Regarding [Rock-id and mineral-id questions. Status](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1786/rock-id-and-mineral-id-questions-status):

There remain some 370 [closed but non-deleted rock id questions](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bidentification-request%5D+closed%3Ayes). The meager 5 delete votes<sup>*</sup> per day of the people trying to move them out of sight do not seem to help much in bringing this number down.
(Additional new ID question are closed quickly and then pop up in this list as well; the [Roomba](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=roomba) will remove those because they have no answers).

If you go to your [moderation tools page](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=delete) it is easy to see the ones that already have at least one delete vote, and you can quickly add an additional vote.

We currently have 47 2k+ users.

<sup>* Higher rep users (over 10000k?) have 14 delete votes</sup>

---

**Update 8 november 2018**

Sorry people, I stop all my 'moderation' activities on this site.
The mess about pronouns and Monica makes me [no longer want to contribute to maintenance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334704/189029).

Good luck with getting rid of these closed questions (list is down to 284 now!).
BTW I just incorrectly voted to reopen a fossil ID questions, but it will probably not survive the review queue ;-)

Comment: I think this may be a prolonged process because everyone can only vote to delete 14 questions each day. I'll do what I can until they're gone.

Comment: Sorry, forgot about this. Will try to remember to do some!

Comment: Been working on it for a week or two, but progress is slow. Did not knew about the mod tool page, this is helping a lot (for me at least). Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: To be precise, it's [one extra delete vote per 1000 extra reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213/172266) (except moderators, whose deletion powers are unlimited and final).  So 5k (12 users) have 8 delete votes, 10k (7 users) have 13 delete votes, and 15k (2 users) have 18 delete votes per day.

Comment: @gerrit could you simply get a morning to delete the rest? This has been enougth democratic

Comment: @Leukocyte I'm in touch with the community team for a more automated solution.

Comment: @JanDoggen Thank you for all your work assisting the moderators on this site (and elsewhere).  I regret but respect your decision and I hope circumstances will change such that you will feel you can return in the future.

Comment: Been deleting daily for a while now - this is getting 'harder' to find posts that I did not already voted on. Is there a way to filter out these?

Comment: @EtienneGodin It does not seem so https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1798/deleting-multiple-questions-i-e-rock-id-questions

Answer (score 4):

There is [one more way](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/help/roomba) to delete most of those questions.  A question is automatically deleted if (emphasis mine):

> If the question was closed more than 9 days ago, and ...

- not closed as a duplicate
- **has a score of 0 or less**
- is not locked
- **has no answers with a score > 0**
- has no accepted answer
- has no pending reopen votes
- has not been edited in the past 9 days

So, unless an answer has been accepted, if users downvote closed questions and answers such that question and answers are all scored 0 or less, the question will be automatically deleted.  However, the preferred option is still deletion, because it's not fair to askers and even less fair to answerers to downvote good quality posts that were declared off-topic *after* it had been posted, so **please only use this option for unanswered questions of questionable quality**.  For example, I just downvoted [this question](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/13207/6) (which doesn't even have a picture!) so this should be automatically deleted.  Even users without vote to close priviliges can do this.

Comment: I might have missed some questions, but I deleted as many as I was able to in late 2019, it took a number of days at 15 questions per day.