# Deleting Multiple Questions - i.e. Rock ID Questions

Tags: support, deleted-questions

Related to the question *[2k+ users Please help delete closed rock ID questions](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1797/2k-users-please-help-delete-closed-rock-id-questions)*.

Given we can only vote 14 times each day to delete questions, is there an easy way for individuals to keep track of the questions they have already voted to be deleted?

Occasionally I vote to delete a question only to informed I've already voted to delete the question. I would like to just list the closed questions I haven't voted to delete so I can vote to delete the first 14 in the list.

Comment: With less rep (but over 2000) it's worse: you can only delete 5. I don't see a way either, I just remember that I'm currently "on page X" of the search results mentioned in my post, and then I can see which links I have visited already. That's not failsafe because I may also have visted them not too long ago for closing.